# Samba vs django's FileWrapper

Tags: python, linux, django, архитектура, samba

Существует система, архитектура которой на момент разработки выглядело следующим образом:

```
                                      +--------+
                               http   | server |
                             <------> +--------+
                                      | nginx  |
                                      | uwsgi  |
                                      | django |
                                      |   db   |
                                      +--------+
```

Но при запуске в будущем в бой хотелось бы иметь масштабируемость и отказоустойчивость системы, поэтому модули были разнесены между собой:

```
                http   +-------+       +-------+       +-------+
              <------> | nginx | <---> |  app  | <---> |  db   |
                       +-------+       +-------+       +-------+
                                       | uwsgi |
                                       | django|
                                       +-------+
```

Появилась проблема с загрузкой изображений, а точнее в отдаче изображения пользователю после загрузки, так как `nginx` из коробки не умеет лезть в файловую систему другого сервера. В связи с этим появились две идеи, как решить данную проблему:

- При помощи `samba` создать общую папку между `nginx` и `app`, в которую `django` будет загружать изображения, и из которой `nginx` будет их тянуть при запросе;
- Использовать `FileWrapper`, чтобы `app` умел сам отдавать изображения на запрос от `nginx`.
- Поставить на `app` ПО для выдачи загруженных изображений: `nginx` или `apache`.

Можете привести аргументы, какое из данных решений лучше использовать, либо привести свое решение?

Comment: Ну только не samba. В *nix мире для этого есть NFS. Кроме того nginx все таки с локольной файлововй системы гарантированно быстрее отдавать будет. Я бы какой нибудь rsync пожалуй замутил, но тут вопрос как часто новые изображения появляются на app и кто их туда кладет

Comment: @Mike, изображения играют ключевую роль системе, и загружают их обычные пользователи. И при этом загрузка будет гораздо чаще, чем выдача. Если считаешь `rsync` лучше, то напиши, чем он лучше.

Comment: Поэтому я и спросил как часто. Если загрузка чаще выдачи - от rsync конечно сложно применим. пытаться синхронизировать каталоги картинок при добавлении каждой будет проблематично. Мне сетевые решения типа samba и даже nfs не очень нравятся, потому как в случае кратковременных обрывов связи они могут после еще какое то время тупить. И процессы обращающиеся к подвисшей точке монтирования могут блокироваться ОС на _минуты_

Comment: Я к сожалению с nginx не работал. Сложно ли будет чисто его настройками организовать, что бы он пытался выдать картинку из локальной папки, а если ее там нет лез по сети на app ?

Comment: а на втором сервере нельзя поднять еще один nginx, чтоб сервил статику? а на первом тогда поставите проксирование

Comment: @DmitryV., думаешь, что это хорошая идея, ставить на `app` еще один nginx только для того, чтобы выдавать загруженные изображения? Может тогда лучше использовать `apache`?

Comment: А в чем практический смысл выноса nginx на отдельный сервер? Отказоустойчивость это не повысит, а скорее наоборот. Появляется вероятность неполадки двух серверов вместо одного, плюс неполадки с каналом между ними.

Comment: @LinnTroll, система развернута на серверах [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/), локальная сетка которых падает достаточно редко. А отказоустойчивость обусловлена тем, что в скором времени появятся несколько серверов `app` и `db`.

Comment: @MichaelPak, В таком случае в вашей схеме должен появится еще отдельно файловый сервер, на который app сервера смогут писать как на примонтированную удаленную файловую систему, а раздовать файлы клиентам он сможет самостоятельно, собственным nginx`ом.

Comment: @LinnTroll, опиши свой вариант в ответах и расскажи, в чем его преимущества.

Comment: @MichaelPak раздавать статику апачем? Нет уж. Всегда делают ровно наоборот, перед apache ставят nginx, на nginx вся статика, а на apache проходят только запросы к приложениям

Comment: @DmitryV., всегда думал, что `apache` легко справляется с раздачей статики и что nginx больше нужен для нагрузки.

Comment: @MichaelPak две секунды в гугле дают [вот](http://ospf-ripe.livejournal.com/754.html) что

Comment: @MichaelPak, два слова: *медленные подключения*. Это - смерть Апача.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С учетом того, что вы хотите маштабироваться за счет увеличения app серверов, предлагаю вам видоизменить схему следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавить еще один сервер, который будет заниматься хранением и раздачей файлов (на схеме File server). app сервера должны иметь папку, в которую будет примонтировано удаленное сетевое хранилище (на схеме обозначено стрелками nfs). Так же предлагаю на файловом сервере установить nginx, который сам будет раздавать файлы клиентам. Для этих целей ему нужно будет выделить поддомен.

Плюсы схемы:

- Минимальная нагрузка и задержка при раздаче файлов. Nginx быстро раздает файлы с локальной файловой системы.
- Дает возможность маштабировать app сервера, решая проблему с хранением файлов на них и последующую раздачу с нескольких серверов.

Минусы:

- Сохранение файлов в сетевую файловую систему замедлит отклик пользователю.
- Для файлового сервера нужно будет выделять поддомен, и реализовывать формирование абсолютных ссылок на файлы с этого поддомена.

Comment: А если я захочу сделать дополнительную обработку изображений? Может имеет смысл сделать на `File server` еще одно маленькое приложение для работы с изображениями?

Comment: Не думаю что это хорошая идея.
Основное приложение вполне справится с обработкой изображения и записью на удаленное хранилище уже измененного.

Хотя если обработка изображения будет занимать много времени и вы готовы отправить пользователя дальше, оставив обработку в фоне, вам все равно прийдется делать для этого некоторую очередь задач. Тогда уже не так важно на каком сервере она будет находится.

Comment: Справедливо, согласен.

Comment: Отличная схема )

Answer (score 2):

Для начала, напишу чего делать *нельзя*: нельзя отдавать статику с сетевой шары. Любое обращение к файлу по сети - это множество пакетов в обе стороны (не забываем, что файл надо найти, открыть, последовательно прочитать, закрыть! - и это еще без авторизации)

В деле отдачи исключительно содержимого файла протокол HTTP оказывается эффективнее, чем SMB или NFS, потому что обращение по этому протоколу - это всегда один запрос, а потом один (длинный) ответ.

---

И так, какие варианты остались?

1. Храним файлы пользователей в БД (а нормальные СУБД позволяют хранить файлы!) Этот способ - единственный способ, при котором гарантируется удаление всех пользовательских файлов при удалении пользователя. Кроме того, это самый простой способ при реализации с нуля.
2. Храним пользовательские файлы на фронтэнде, заливаем их туда через сетевую шару. Самый простой способ если у вас уже реализовано хранение файлов в файловой системе. Фактически, не надо даже изменять код - достаточно подмонтировать папку `uploads` на сервере `app`, чтобы она реально находилась на сервере `nginx`. Т.е. это задача сисадмина, а не программиста.
3. Вариант, приведенный @LinnTroll. Используется во всех хостингах картинок - должно же это хоть что-то значить? Но при этом этот вариант одновременно и самый трудный в реализации.
4. Отдельный `nginx` на `app`. Привожу для полноты картины, недостатков у этого варианта - куча. Главный из них - как будет вести себя фронтэнд-nginx, когда app-серверов будет несколько? И будут ли синхронизироваться между ними файлы? Проблемы решаемые, но лучше их не создавать.
5. Модификация варианта, предложенного @LinnTroll: пользователь забирает файлы с `fileserver` не напрямую, а через фронтэнд. Этот вариант похож на вариант 1, но более масштабируем: можно наращивать число файловых серверов при необходимости. Можно применять этот вариант вместо третьего если "не выдают" IP-адреса или поддомены.